# Sed Command in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, text, sed, extract

Hi I need to extract text variables out of a text file right now I have the text displaying in one chunk like this

```
   JIMENEZ  ** 353743
VALERIE ROSE Bed No. 121203 7/2 VALE ROAD MOUNT COLAH   Acc .# K00525 Aae79 2079
Ph: (02) 9987-4333 PEN: None    DOB:    19/02/1935
```

I would like to be able to extract the text into single strings such as the phone number or the DOB.

```
NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

textView.text = result;
```

This is the code I currently have and the text is getting downloaded from my server.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: like 19/02/1935 out of that file

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the below grep command to get the Phone number and the DOB.

```
grep -oP '(Ph|DOB):\s*\K.*?(?=\s+[A-Z]|$)' file
```

OR

You could try the below sed command.

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(Ph: *.*\) PEN:.*\(DOB *[^ ]*\)/\1 \2/p' file
Ph: (02) 9987-4333 DOB:    19/02/1935
```